# Refer to the value of switch statement in a branch

Tags: swift

Is there a way in Swift to refer to the value I am switching on in a branch? For example:

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
  // cases
  default:
    fatalError("User interface idiom \(value) is not supported")
}
```

I am thinking about something similar to the implicit `error` reference inside `catch` block:

```
do {
  // ...
} catch {
  print(error) // 'error' is defined implicitly
}
```

Of course, I can create a variable myself, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in variable, but you can easily capture the value yourself with the `case let` pattern:

```
switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
  // cases
case let value:
    fatalError("User interface idiom \(value) is not supported")
}
```

Note: This will match anything, so it replaces the `default` case and it should be the last `case` in your `switch`.

---

You can use a `where` clause to allow the capture of values other than *everything*:

```
switch 1 + 2 * 3 {
case let value where 0...9 ~= value:
    print("The value \(value) is a single digit value")
case let value:
    print("\(value) is not a single digit value.")
}
```

but it would be easier in that case just to assign the value to the variable before the `switch`.